# How do I give one user read/write access to everything another user has access to?

Tags: permissions, users, groups

I have a situation where I have to work as user `alice`, and I need to be able to read, write, and edit directories and files created by `bob`.  I know that I could take a specific directory created by `bob`, and give alice permission to access it with `chown` or `chmod`.  But sometimes `bob` will be creating new files and directories himself, and I want to be able to access those as `alice` easily, without having to do a `chown` for every time `bob` creates something new.

How do I give `alice` access to everything exists or will ever exist in `/home/bob/` (assuming only Bob is creating files there)?

Comment: This seems like the classic use case for 'groups'.

Comment: apart from groups you could use ACL - Access Control Lists https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man5/acl.5.html